# What does "customized website" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does *customized website* mean?

> 1) a website with unique design and features.

or

> 2) a website that I can change, for example, add new page without
>   writing a code.

**Update** with the context:

I get an email from one client. He wants some website (original quote, just price and city are changed).

> Are you going to make **customized  website** with xxx$? I have price in my city Y xxxx$, so your price is way better. Just I want to make sure. Are you going to customized my dashboard and database with xxx$? I need to control my web by myself. So I need you make very friendly if in future I want add so pages will able to do myself.

And here I don't understand what exactly *customized* means.

Comment: Perhaps you should be asking this question on a different website. Try StackOverflow, but best search through their archives before posting your question.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a programming site. Here I ask the meaning of the expression.

Comment: Please add some context. There may be useful information in four or five sentences which cannot be gleaned from just two words.

Comment: @AndrewLeach see upd

Comment: I think you should probably ask your client exactly what he wants -- it shouldn't really be for random bods on the internet to interpret a client request for you (what if we got it wrong?!). But, since his English is not exactly top-notch, and he asks for a site he can change easily, you could just tell him exactly what you will supply. That may include both (1) and (2). It appears from his last sentence that he is more interested in (2).

Comment: I would interpret "customized website" to mean one where the customer/purchaser has considerable latitude to prescribe the layout and function of the the site, vs just parameterizing a standard layout & its function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP Is asking us to interpret what his customer wants, and anything beyond what Andrew Leach said in his comment would be speculation.

Answer (score 2):

Does, "customized website", mean:

> 1) a website with unique design and features

Yes.

> 2) a website that I can change, for example, add new page without writing a code.

No.  That would be a customizable website.  Not every customized web site remains customizeable after deployment.  We happen to be customising this one as we type.  But that changes the content.  Not the design.  We're also doing it after it was deployed.

Before being deployed EL&U had some customizations made.  Among other tweaks it was given a different title, logo, and background color.  Even the voting controls were changed.  These were customizations.  But as far as I know not a single line of code was changed.  Just configuration.

The paragraph is asking for two customizations:  the dashboard and the database.  It is also asking that the site be easily customizable "to control my web[sic.] myself".  This last feature already exists in other websites.

> **cus·tom·ize**
>
> *ˈkəstəˌmīz*
>   *verb*
>   *past tense: customized; past participle: customized*
>
> modify (something) to suit a particular individual or task.
>
> "the suit can be customized for every skydiving need"
>
> [google.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+customized&oq=define+customized&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i59j0l3.1359j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

If we were talking about clothing it would be simpler.  Buy off the rack, get what they have.  Go to a tailor, get a custom fit suit.  The problem with websites is there is a whole confusing range between these extremes.  The quoted paragraph is attempting to nail down where on that range the website will fall.

I can make, very cheaply, a site that says nothing but "Hello world".  Having done it once I could offer it again even cheaper.  But would anyone want that?

At the other end of the spectrum is a fully maintained actively developed website that can have it's design changed on a whim.

In between are the websites that allow content to change but are not actively developed so no code get's changed.  These are deployed cookie cutter style: A shopping cart site.  A blog.  A stackexchange.  The code is always the same but the content is different.

Slightly better are sites designed specifically for the customers unique needs.  A custom site goes beyond content variations (my answer here is an example of content).  A custom site respects the customers individual needs whatever they are.

Every choice to be different than anything that existed before costs time and money.  Which is why the paragraph keeps asking what exactly they're getting for their money.